# Scala job scheduler with MongoDB jobs storage

Tags: scala, mongodb, job-scheduling

I'm looking for simple Job Scheduler for using in Scala that can store jobs in Mongo or at least that can be simply extended to use Mongo as storage.

Can anybody suggest the best solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple but extensible scheduler system can be built with Akka:

```scala
import akka.actor._
import akka.util.duration._

val system = ActorSystem("SchedulerTest")
case object Job

val runnerActor = system.actorOf(Props(
   new Actor{ 
      def receive = { case Job => println("run " + self.path.name)}
   } 
))

//schedule a Job message to the actor in 500 ms
system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(500 milliseconds, runnerActor, Job)

//system.scheduler.schedule(0 milliseconds, 50 milliseconds, runnerActor, Job) //this repeats a message every 50 ms
```

The worker actor can optionally schedule further events.
Serializing the configuration to a db can be done many different ways.

[Akka 2.0 Doc on Scheduler](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.1/scala/scheduler.html)